# Yosemite + Fusion 7.0.1 now gets "Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory." and will not start any VM

Tags: osx, vmware

I've been on Yosemite on this machine since it hit released, and on Fusion 7 since it released.  Now on 10.10.1 and 7.0.1 respectively.

On one machine http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i7-3.4-27-inch-aluminum-late-2012-specs.html everything was working fine, when suddenly both Win 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.1 VMs froze with an "internal VMWare issue".  I elected to get the dump from one of them, then when it was done, rebooted the Mac.

Now when I try to start any VM on that machine, I get "Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory."  I tried the http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003484 methods in the KB article, un-install, download, install, repair disk permissions, reboot, and no difference.  Anyone seen a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.  Spent a couple hours on phone with VMWare support (they are awesome BTW).  Tried all manner of things, then I noticed a similar error in /var/log/system.log from smbfs.  re-applied the 10.10.1 update, and everything works.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I found that VirtualBox was interfering with VMWare Fusion 7.1 on Yosemite.

The solution was to completely uninstall VirtualBox using [this script](http://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Installer/darwin/DiskImage/VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool).

- Download VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool
- Open the Terminal
- Browse to the directory where you downloaded it
- Run it with `sudo sh VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool`

Comment: This was the fix for me after updating to Sierra 2 days ago. Getting rid of VirtualBox immediately fixed my issues in VMWare Fusion 8.5.

Comment: Thanks Brad! That was the solution for Sierra. I have been struggling to figure this out but I can confirm that after using the tool VMWare pro 8.5 back and ticking again.